# Stream Table FQL Query

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I want to get the posts of my friends order by updated_time, this query works fine for single friend when I use source = first_friend_id but when I use this query with in it return empty data.

```
SELECT post_id,type,message, actor_id,likes.user_likes,likes.count,likes.friends,comments.comment_list, comments.count , target_id ,updated_time,created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id in(friend_id1,friend_id2,friend_id3) ORDER BY updated_time DESC LIMIT 5
```

Can someone please point out how to get the latest 5 feeds of amoung 3 friends.

source_id = friend_id works fine, but it only work for 1 friends

I'm testing it here.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's been a number of posts like this recently... It appears the `stream` table is simply acting very finicky lately, as the logic of that query is valid. Your best bet is to report a detailed bug [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/)